# Finding variable value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

$a$,$b$ and $c$ are real numbers each bigger than 1 such that

$$\frac{2}{3}log_b{a} + \frac{3}{5}log_c{b} + \frac{5}{2}log_a{c} = 3$$

If the value of $b$ is 9 what must be the value of $a$?

I tried putting in the value of $b$ as 9 and then used the base change formula but couldn’t come up with a solution. Can someone help me out with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$log_b a = \frac {\log a}{\log b}$

$\frac {2\log a}{3\log b} + \frac {3\log b}{5\log c} + \frac {5\log c}{2\log a} = 3$

let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma = 2\log a, 3\log b, 5\log c$ respectively

The AM-GM inequality.

$\frac 13 (\frac {\alpha}{\beta} + \frac {\beta}{\gamma} + \frac {\gamma}{\alpha}) \ge (\frac {\alpha}{\beta} \frac {\beta}{\gamma} \frac {\gamma}{\alpha})^\frac 13$

$(\frac {\alpha}{\beta} \frac {\beta}{\gamma} \frac {\gamma}{\alpha})^\frac 13 = 1$

If
$(\frac {\alpha}{\beta} + \frac {\beta}{\gamma} + \frac {\gamma}{\alpha}) = 3$

We can conclude:

$\frac {\alpha}{\beta} = \frac {\beta}{\gamma} = \frac {\gamma}{\alpha} = 1$

$2\log a = 3\log b = 5\log c\\
a^2 = b^3 = c^5$

$b = 9 = 3^2\\
a^2= b^3 = 3^6\\
a = 3^3\\
c = 3^{\frac 65}$

Comment: Amazing solution, how did it strike you to use the A.M. G.M. Inequality? Thanks a lot